# NEAR smart-contract error: "Contract is not initialized"

Tags: nearprotocol, assemblyscript

I created NEAR smart-contract using Assembly Script and deployed to testnet.
When I call any function I receiving error that contract is not initialised (contract was added to workspaces in asconfig.json):

```
Error: {"index":0,"kind":{"ExecutionError":"Smart contract panicked: contract is not initialized, filename: \"src/token/assembly/index.ts\" line: 123 col: 3"}}
ServerTransactionError: {"index":0,"kind":{"ExecutionError":"Smart contract panicked: contract is not initialized, filename: \"src/token/assembly/index.ts\" line: 123 col: 3"}}
```

[First lines of my contract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDgx8.png)

Answer (score 2):

This error can occur when you have a Singleton style contract, and a `constructor(){}` in it. If you don't use the constructor, just remove it. Or, you can call it with zero arguments when you deploy the contract:

```
near deploy --accountId example-contract.testnet --wasmFile out/singleton.wasm --initFunction new --initArgs '{}'
```

or using dev-deploy, without passing an accountId to generate a new dev-account

```
near dev-deploy --wasmFile out/singleton.wasm --initFunction new --initArgs '{}'
```

If you have a constructor with some arguments, you need to pass the arguments when you deploy it as well

```
near deploy --accountId example-contract.testnet --wasmFile out/singleton.wasm --initFunction new --initArgs '{"name":"someName"}'
```

```ts
@nearBindgen
export class Contract {
 name: string;
 // If the constructor is empty without any argumanets, just remove it, and you don't have to think about init.
 // constructor(){}
 
 // When you have some arguments in the constructor, you need to call init after it's deployed. 
 constructor(name:string){
   this.name = name;
 }

}
```

If the contract is already deployed, which I think is the case when you get this error in the first place, you can also call `init` afterwards

```
near call example-contract.testnet init '{"name":"someName"}' --accountId example-contract.testnet
```

More information can be found in [NEAR's documentation](https://docs.near.org/docs/tools/near-cli#near-deploy)

Answer (score 0):

I was using Singleton style for my code and in this way it is required to init my contract before using.
Simplest way: use just functions (without Singleton).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).